# How to run this code in series using verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

The following code is compiled and is working in parallel, Please help me to make these code work sequentially, i.e after stage1 counter should reset itself and starts from 0 for the stage2. The following codes has Module1- stage1 and module2-stage2. This is the process flow in which one stage occur after completion of another. For example when stage 1 is done then counter reset itself and then stage 2 starts with count zero.Here stage 1 module has counter that counts till 18 and stage 2 counter counts 8.

```
    module stage1(
                input Clk, //50 Hz clock
                input x0,
                input reset,
                output reg y0,y1,y2,y3,y5,y7,y10,y15,
                output reg stage1_done
                );                
        reg [15:0] counter = 0;
        parameter F = 50;                  
        always@ (posedge Clk or posedge reset)
            if(reset) begin
                counter <= 0;
                {y0,y1,y2,y3,y5,y7,y10,y15} <= 8'b00000000;
                stage1_done <= 0;
            end else begin  
                if(x0 == 1) begin
                    if(counter == 18*F)
                        stage1_done <= 1;
                    else begin
                        counter <= counter + 1;
                        stage1_done <= 0;
                    end 
                    if(counter >= 1*F && counter < 10*F)
                        y0 <= 1;
                    else
                        y0 <= 0;
                    if(counter >= 1*F && counter < 17*F)
                        y1 <= 1;
                    else
                        y1 <= 0;
                    if(counter >= 1*F && counter < 9*F)
                        y2 <= 1;
                    else
                        y2 <= 0;
                    if(counter >= 11*F && counter < 16*F)
                        y3 <= 1;
                    else
                        y3 <= 0;
                    if(counter >= 1*F && counter < 18*F)
                        y5 <= 1;
                    else
                        y5 <= 0;
                    if(counter >= 1*F && counter < 5*F)
                        y7 <= 1;
                    else
                        y7 <= 0;
                    if(counter >= 1*F && counter < 5*F)
                        y10 <= 1;
                    else
                        y10 <= 0;
                    if((counter >= 2*F && counter < 9*F) || (counter >= 13*F && counter < 17*F))
                        y15 <= 1;
                    else
                        y15 <= 0;   
                end         
            end 

        endmodule
```

//Module for stage 2;

```
    module stage2(
            input x0,
            input Clk, //50 Hz clock
            input reset,
            output reg y1,y3,y5,
            output reg stage2_done 
            );            
    reg [15:0] counter = 0;
    parameter F = 50;         
    always@ (posedge Clk or posedge reset)
        if(reset) begin
            counter <= 0;
            {y1,y3,y5} <= 3'b000;
            stage2_done <= 0;
        end 
    else begin   if(x0 == 1) begin
            if(counter == 8*F)
                stage2_done <= 1;
            else begin
                counter <= counter + 1;
                stage2_done <= 0;
            end 
            if(counter >= 1*F && counter < 8*F)
                y1 <= 1;
            else
                y1 <= 0;
            if(counter >= 1*F && counter < 8*F)
                y3 <= 1;
            else
                y3 <= 0;
            if(counter >= 1*F && counter < 8*F)
                y5 <= 1;
            else
                y5 <= 0;
            end                     
        end 

    endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a counter from `stage2` module to start counting after `counter` from `stage1` finishes, then you have to "inform" it that the other one finished counting. In your case you can use `stage1_done` signal and feed it to `stage2` module. Use this signal as a condition for counter to start counting initially. Also, shouldn't you reset the `counter` from `stage1` back to `0` when you assert `stage1_done`?

Comment: I tried doing the same, but couldn't come up with any correct solution. Can you show me how to proceed, like how can I reset the counter in stage 1 and provide stage1_done condition to stage2.

Thanks!

Comment: Declare `stage1_done` as input to the `stage2` module, route it from `stage1` to `stage2` on the top level. To reset the `counter` in `stage1` assign `0's` to it when you assert `stage1_done`.

Comment: I have iterate many times but couldn't get the desired result, I tried using condition like if (stage1_done <=1) begin
counter <=0;
end and few other conditions but I am not getting results.

Please tell me how u'r trying to make this work by implementing. I mean just comment down the syntax which can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as a state machine. with 2 or 3 states, i.e. `reset`, `stage1`, `stage2`. You need to think over the conditions which would move from one stage to another. You provided one condition: stage1 counter overflow has to go from stage1 to stage2. There are definitely few question: what happens to stage1 while stage2 is running, what what happens when stage 2 is finished. What happens during reset?

So, I suggest that you create yest another module to implement the state machine logic:

```
module control(clk, ...);
    enum { reset, stage1, stage2} state, next_state;

    always_ff @( posedge clk)
        case (state)
        reset: 
              if (!resetSig) next_state <= stage1;
              else if (resetSig) next_state <= reset;
        stage1:
              if (stage1Done) next)state <= stage2;
              ...
       endcase

   assign state = next_state;
```

Now in every stage you just use `state` as an enable condition.

```
  module stage1(clk, state, stageDone, ...)
     always_ff
         if (state == reset)
              do reset
         else if (state == stage1)
              do stage1 

     assign stageDone = counter == max_value;
```

and so on. Yes, you will need to pass extra ports for the state machine controls, but you will make your code much more manageable and readable and confirm to industry practices.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the explanation, I got a hint to move further but i am using verilog and the above mention code is suitable in system verilog.

Comment: @p_ka it is suitabel for verilog as well. I used system verilog always blocks since you tagged it a 'system verilog'. The only difference is in the types of the always blocks you use and enums. you can replays ` always_ff @( posedge clk)` with ` always @( posedge clk)` and use params or macros to encode your states instead of enum.